# Compute $\int_{0}^{\pi} P^1_l(\cos(\theta))P^1_l(\cos(\theta-\alpha))\sin(\theta)d\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, legendre-polynomials

I wanna compute

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} P^1_l(\cos(\theta))P^1_l(\cos(\theta-\alpha))\sin(\theta)d\theta$$

Where $P^1_l(\cos(\theta))$ is the associated Legendre polynomial of order $1$ and degree $l$, and $\alpha$ is a constant.

I'm pretty much stuck, and can do nothing about it.

Comment: I can't say anything too clever either at the moment, but one thing to note is that the integral is $\pi$-periodic in $\alpha$ owing to $P_l^1(-x)=(-1)^l P_l^1 (x)$ and orthogonality.

Comment: Actually, check out the identity here (consider the case $\phi=\phi_1$)$: http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP2/23/01/0002/